# geodjango - not recognizing PostGIS function on Amazon RDS

Tags: geodjango

I have a latitude & longitude result from a geocoder and need to find out which MultiPolygon geometry these coordinates fall into.  The PostGIS query would be:

`select * from gis.zipcodes where ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-74.0863037109375 40.704586878965245)', 4269));`

where geom is the multipolygon geometry column.  I tried this by doing:

`pnt = GEOSGeometry('SRID=4269;POINT(-74.0863037109375 40.704586878965245)')`
`Zipcode.objects.filter(geom__contains=pnt)`

but received the error "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

I then tried making a raw query like:

`Zipcode.objects.raw("select * from gis.zipcodes where ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-74.0863037109 40.704586879)', 4269))")`

and received the error below.  I copied and pasted this query into psql and it works as expected. My guess is that Django isn't recognizing the PostGIS extensions but I'm not sure why.  I have added django.contrib.gis to INSTALLED_APPS, set db ENGINE to django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis, added POSTGIS_VERSION = ( 2, 1 ) and POSTGIS_TEMPLATE = 'template1' to my settings and run CREATE EXTENSION postgis; on my database.  I've also tried a few other queries and received similar errors.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 403, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 400, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/django-apis/hcpro/proapp/views.py", line 47, in zipcode_from_coord
    print raw_qs[0]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1598, in __getitem__
    return list(self)[k]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1535, in __iter__
    query = iter(self.query)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 76, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 90, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, self.params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: function st_geomfromtext(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...elect * from gis.zipcodes where ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeomFro...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the search path not being set correctly.  I had the schema set correctly in the model using:

```
class Zipcode
    ...
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False, blank=False)
    ...
    geom = models.GeometryField(srid=4269)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'zipcodes'
        in_db = 'gis'

    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

and when I defined the database in the settings.py file I used the same "gis" schema for the search path.  The problem is, the GIS features are in the public schema.  Defining the database like this in settings.py resolved the issue:

```
'gis': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': "gis",
    'OPTIONS': {
        'options': '-c search_path=gis,public,pg_catalog'
    },
    'USER': DB_DEFAULT.user,
    'PASSWORD': DB_DEFAULT.password,
    'HOST': DB_DEFAULT.host,
    'PORT': DB_DEFAULT.port,
}
```